# Baofeng GT-3WP Cross Band Operation?

Tags: baofeng, crossband-repeat

The [Baofeng GT-3WP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BSL58Z6) has a feature labeled "Cross band reception / transmission".  Does that mean it will function as a Cross-Band Repeater?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a Baofeng handheld with similar specifications, and the short answer is no, it does not function as a repeater in any way - cross band or otherwise. I would imagine that would be a feature they would be quite specific about.

---

The long answer is that you can operate between both bands to use a cross-band repeater or satellite. Using software like Chirp, you can program duplex operation with the regular +/- offsets as in columns 3 & 6 of this screen shot using 2M repeaters as an example:

[image: 2 Meter Repeaters]

or you can enter your receive frequency and select "split" instead of the +/- offset. You would then enter the frequency of the transmit band in the column usually used for the offset as in this image:

[image: Satellite Settings]

This is the capability they are stating.

Answer (score 1):

The manual for that radio doesn't seem to specify, so I would guess that it is capable of communicating with a cross-band repeater, but probably not capable of acting as one.

Found the manual here:
http://s3.image.ro.s3.amazonaws.com/download/GT-3WP-manual.pdf

Comment: >>"I would guess that it is capable of communicating with a cross-band repeater"
Can you give an example of a radio that isn't?

Comment: I would guess that it means that you can configure the radio to transmit on 70cm when you press PTT and receive on 2m when you release PTT (or vice versa).

Comment: Upvote because that radio cannot both transmit and receive simultaneously.